# How to merge two dataframes in pandas having multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a sales dataframe with product id from 2015-2019. I have to merge it with product_theme _list which contains the theme id for the given product id. But the same product id has different theme ids available . So how do i merge the two dataframes?

Comment: What did you try? Please, consider sharing a minimal example so that others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.merge to merge 2 dataframes into a single dataframe which contains all informations of both. I hope that helps.

```
sales_data = {'product_id':['1','2','3','1','2','3']
,'supplier_part_num':['4711','1111','9999','4711','1111','9999']
,'year':['2018','2018','2018','2019','2019','2019']}

product_theme_list = {'product_id':['1','1','2','2','3','3']
,'theme_id':['77','88','99','22','44','55']}

df_themes = pd.DataFrame(product_theme_list)
df_sales = pd.DataFrame(sales_data)

merged_df = pd.merge(df_sales
,df_themes
,how='left'
,left_on='product_id'
,right_on='product_id'
,sort=True)
```

Comment: If you do this wont it increase your records in sales data. The same product id will be assigned to the two theme ids which will make our data wrong